# Run intern functional tests against static web app on localhost

Tags: javascript, functional-testing, intern

I have a static web app. Html, JS (requirejs modules), and some CSS.
Currently the 'serverUrl' is being set through a property module, which i can 'require' and use values from it:

```
define({
    serverUrl: 'https://some.api/path/'
})
```

I have Intern setup to run functional tests in the browser using src/index.html as the entry point.

```
return this.remote
    .get(require.toUrl('src/index.html'))
```

Given the `serverUrl` is hardcoded in the properties file, I'm trying to find a way to run tests against the web app where `serverUrl` is pointing to `localhost:1234/someFakeServer` so I can test error scenarios and such.

I've trawled the web but can't find anyone doing anything remotely similar to me, which makes me think I'm doing something obviously wrong. There's solutions for NODE apps, using config modules, but because I never 'start' my web app - its just files, these won't work for me.

Some solutions I've thought about, but can't figure out how to achieve:

- Intern is proxying the files on :9000, so if I can somehow 'build' an application with another properties file pointing to localhost, all is good. But I've no idea how to do that - I've looked at webpack and similar but they don't seem to do what I want.
- I've looked at Interns 'Setup' config item, which allows a function to be run before the tests are started - so I thought about modifying the properties file in there, but seems too hacky and not sure how I'd put it back...

Comment: So the overall goal is for the app to use a serverUrl that is configured by Intern?

Comment: Doesn't have to be configured by intern, i just need it to be configurable per environment and intern to be able to run against any of said environments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the properties file is accessible to Intern, you could simply have Intern load the properties file and pull the server URL out of it. If you have multiple potential properties files, the one being used can be set in the Intern config or passed in as a custom command line variable (which would be used to set a property in the Intern config). The test module can get the name of the properties file from Intern's config and then load the relevant file. It could look something like this (untested):

```
// intern config
define({
    // ...
    propertiesFile: 'whatever',
})

// test file
define([ 'intern', ... ], function (intern, ...) {
    registerSuite({
        // ...
        'a test': function () {
            var did = this.async();
            var remote = this.remote;
            require([
                intern.config.propertiesFile
            ], dfd.callback(function (props) {
                return remote.get(props.url)
                    .otherStuff
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I may be missing something - but its not Intern that need to access the property - its the web app. Intern will still load up the web app using `require.toUrl('src/index.html')` - its just the web app needs to load the properties file that points to localhost.

Comment: How does the web app normally load the properties file?

Comment: Its just a require module as described in the Q. I've managed to get it working by basically using NPM to run some shell commands to copy files from /src/* to /dist/ and then copying over the right properties file afterwards.  `"package:test": "cp -R ./src ./dist && cp config/local/properties.js ./dist/js/app"`

Comment: Ah, so your goal is just to get a config file into the app directory before the test page is loaded? You could have Intern do that in your intern.js, or your test file (or the npm script works fine).